# Html to PDF using Node JS without using browser dependency in Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, pdf

I have need to create html to pdf in Node JS (Typescript).
I have used Puppeeter but in production there is chromium dependency which we need to install in our Linux server. I don't want to install any browser dependency like chromium.

Please let me know if we can use any node package as per our requirement.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Which npm packages have you tried? There are many that do this.

Comment: We have tried multiple npm package like html-pdf, pdfKit, puppeeter, html-pdf-node. do you know other than these in which we dont need to install chromium dependency.